# jQuery Tools Scrollable Width 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-tools, fluid

I’m working on a scrollable (jQuery Tools) slider where I have a wide background image at each slide (so that most screens widths are covered), but now I’m stuck to make the scrollable slider 100% wide.

How can I make it fluid to 100% with a min-width 960px?

I’ve used the code from this [example](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/one-sized.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
.css-panes {
  min-width: 960px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

If so, what's the issue you're facing?

Comment: You can have a look at it [here](http://starflower.at/kuerbis/index.html)

The problem is, that I also have to set the width of the individual divs `.css-panes div`, otherwise they would just be as wide as its content. 
In my example the width is set to 1300px but if I set it to 100% my inspector says its 258000px wide…

Comment: Since the scroller is set up in a way that all of the images are held side by side in one long div, you're not going to be able to use `width: 100%;` to match the width of the page. You're going to have to get the width of the window using `var $windowwidth = $(window).width();` and assign it as the background-size of the windows here: `$('.css-panes div div').css("background-size", $windowwidth);`.

Comment: But what do I do with my CSS width rules for .css-panes and .css-panes div?

Comment: Keep the `.css-panes { min-width: 960px; width: 100%; }` the script will take care of the rest. Unless you want to rewrite the scroll plugin script. :)

Comment: Nope, that doesn’t work. Because there is the whole container `.css-panes` which is as wide as my browser window. Then there is an additional wrapper `.items` which is 20000em wide. And then there are my individual divs. Setting my individual div width to `100%` makes them 20000em wide. That is basically my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this: http://cooshtee.com/blog/2013/04/making-jquery-tools-scrollable-responsive/
Hope this will help!